# How to use the content search web part to filter on a custom user profile property

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We added the department number from AD to sharepoint.  This property is multi valued in AD, and its multivalue in sharepoint.

My user profile screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/e9xaZMyJJ2

Then in the CSWP, I want to filter by this value, please check here:

http://screencast.com/t/rlP95vrYRB3E

If I check the TEST, its using a GUID instead of the 613 code

http://screencast.com/t/ASltLUsIP

I am totally clueless.!! any idea?

Mapped property screenshot here:

http://screencast.com/t/gLXs2ZIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your user profile the department number is stored as a 'term' using a managed metadata field. 
It's important to know that a 'term' can be translated or you can even define synonyms.

When using managed metadata in search, search will use the id (=a guid) of the term instead of the actual text ('613').

Since it ignores the text (and uses the id of the term), this makes it possible for search to find your term in any language or synonyms.

In your case translation of '613' is not really applicable but imagine that your department was a text instead of a number. 
When searching on the term 'HR', search could return all the items with 'HR' but also the ones with 'personeelsdienst' (HR in Dutch).